# Combinatorial Proof for $\Sigma_{i=0}^r \binom{i + m -1}{m - 1} = \binom{m + r}{m}$ where $m\geq1$ and $r\geq0$

Tags: combinatorics, solution-verification, proof-writing, combinations, combinatorial-proofs

I am trying to prove algebraically and using combinatorics that

$$\sum_{i=0}^r \binom{i + m -1}{m - 1}  = \binom{m + r}{m}$$
where $m\geq1$ and $r\geq0$

The algebraic proof went smoothly but I am confused as to what the left hand side means. I understand the right hand side is showing how to choose $m$ elements out of $m+r$ elements, but how does that relate to the left hand side?

Comment: Formatting note:  use \sum instead of \sigma for a better display.

Comment: To your question, Hint:    to specify $m$ choices out of $r+m$ options, you just need to choose $m-1$ out of the options that precede the last one

Comment: Do you know that the number of ways to solve $n=x_1+\cdots+x_m$ where the $x_i$ are positive integers is $\binom{n+m-1}{m-1}?$ This is usually proved using the "stars and bars" technique. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)?wprov=sfti1

Comment: So the right side is the number of ways to write $r$ and the sum of $m+1$ numbers, and the left side is the number of ways to write all numbers $\leq r$ as the sum of $m$ numbers.